# What's the 'alternative forms of sexuality'?

Tags: meaning-in-context, sexual-minorities

> The Beat Generation is a group of American post-WWII writers who came to prominence in the 1950s, as well as the cultural phenomena that they both documented and inspired. Central elements of "Beat" culture included experimentation with drugs and **alternative forms of sexuality**.

BTW, does the Beat Generation only refer to writers?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Alternative forms of sexuality would mean anything not heterosexual. The quick list:

- homosexual
- bisexual
- transsexual

Strictly speaking, people get pretty creative in their sexual practices and the terms come and go:

- pansexual
- bestiality
- queer

If I understand correctly, *queer* is technically a gender issue but it tends to get lumped into the same topic of "LGBT" which stands for "Lesiban Gay Bisexual Transgender".

Comment: [Polysexuality](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polysexuality)

Comment: *Queer* is usually used as an umbrella term for QUILTBAG people. It's better than the alphabet soup which gets tossed around sometimes.

Comment: Um... "Transsexual" is an orientation related to gender & sex, not sexuality.

Comment: Also, *bestiality* is not an orientation, but an action.

Answer (score 1):

The Beats included figures like Allen Ginsberg, Jack Kerouac, and Lawrence Ferlinghetti. These were mainly poets and writers, with some elements of performance art seen among their collected works. "Alternative sexuality" in the quote above refers to non-hetereosexuality. This was not a defining characteristic of the Beats as a group, but some members were fairly forward about it at a time when doing so was highly unusual.