# What does "even the Generation is still in motion" mean in this passage?

Tags: meaning-in-context

> The Beat Generation is a group of American post-WWII writers who came to prominence in the 1950s, as well as the cultural phenomena that they both documented and inspired. Central elements of "Beat" culture included experimentation with drugs and alternative forms of sexuality, an interest in Eastern religion, a rejection of materialism, and the idealizing of exuberant, unexpurgated means of expression and being. **Even still the Generation is in motion**.

Comment: -1; I realize that we are here to help people understand English but I am not comfortable with the idea of you copying paragraphs from Wikipedia and [asking about every detail](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/23247/whats-the-alternative-forms-of-sexuality).

Comment: That being said, thanks for asking them as separate questions. :)

Comment: http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2011/02/are-some-questions-too-simple/

Comment: Anyway, I'm a bit puzzled by the correctness of that sentence. It should either be *Even so,* or just *Still*.  *Even still* is just plain horrible.

Comment: @nico: "Even still" is okay as far as I know. I would use a comma: "Even still, they are in motion." Or _even now_, _even today_.

Comment: I think, "Even now" is much better to understand.

Comment: @MrHen, @lovespring: that's exactly my point! What idea is that sentence trying to convey? *Even now* or *Even so*? They mean different things. The first means that the Generation is still in motion nowadays. The second that the Generation is still in motion, despite all that happened in the past.

Comment: Please correct either the thread title or the quote. They are different.  The version in the title makes some kind of sense. The other doesn't.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That this generation is still changing, still as open to new ideas as they were in the 1950s.